# While Loop In Echo Statement - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute `while` loop in echo statement.

My code snippet is here:

```
$sql="select distinct(attribute) from categorywithfilter where subcategory='$cat'";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$sub=$res['attribute'];
$sqlfilter="select * from categorywithfilter where attribute='$sub' ";
$queryfilter=mysql_query($sqlfilter);

echo " <div class='form-group'>
            <label  class='col-sm-2 control-label'>$sub</label>
            <div class='col-sm-6'>

              <select name='category' class='form-control' id='filter'>
                while($resf=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryfilter)){
                    echo'ok';
                }

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>";
}
```

But it's not working.

Plz help me out

Comment: What error message you are seeing?

Comment: `echo "Stuff"; while(x) { echo "More"; } echo "End";` - what is it with people trying to do everything at once?

Comment: Then get the while out of your echo.

Answer (score 0):

Then just do it like this:

```
echo "Anything you want";
while(....) {
   echo " ... ";
}
echo "Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

As quick solution try this one

```
$sql="select distinct(attribute) from categorywithfilter where subcategory='$cat'";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$sub=$res['attribute'];
$sqlfilter="select * from categorywithfilter where attribute='$sub' ";
$queryfilter=mysql_query($sqlfilter);

echo " <div class='form-group'>
            <label  class='col-sm-2 control-label'>$sub</label>
            <div class='col-sm-6'>

              <select name='category' class='form-control' id='filter'>";
                while($resf=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryfilter)){
                    echo 'ok';
                }

            echo  "</select>
            </div>
          </div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable and keep appending the output you require.

Print result in the end as follows.

```
$output = ""

while($resf=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryfilter)){

$output .= " div and other html tags ";

        /*Append whatever you want*/


$output .= " /div";

}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql="select distinct(attribute) from categorywithfilter where subcategory='$cat'";
   $query=mysql_query($sql);
   while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
   $sub=$res['attribute'];
   $sqlfilter="select * from categorywithfilter where attribute='$sub' ";
   $queryfilter=mysql_query($sqlfilter);
    ?>


         <div class='form-group'>
         <label  class='col-sm-2 control-label'><?php echo $sub; ?></label>
         <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <select name='category' class='form-control' id='filter'>
       <?php
      while($resf=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryfilter)){
      echo'ok'; 
       }
      ?>
     </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use while loop in wcho but you can do something like this.

```
<?php

    $sql="select distinct(attribute) from categorywithfilter where subcategory='$cat'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);

    while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $sub=$res['attribute'];
        $sqlfilter="select * from categorywithfilter where attribute='$sub' ";
        $queryfilter=mysql_query($sqlfilter);

?>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label  class='col-sm-2 control-label'>$sub</label>
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                  <select name='category' class='form-control' id='filter'>

        <?php
                    while($resf=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryfilter)){
                        echo'ok'; # wrap ok with option tag
                    }
        ?>

                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
<?php

    }

?>
```

This example is only for purpose of solving your problem with while loop in echo.